# how to create a graph in Android Studio with data from MySQL database?

Tags: android

I need to create a graph in Android Studio using data taken from a MySQL database, can someone give me some hints on which libraries it's better to use?
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart%3EMPAndroidChart).

First get Mysql data from API and store it into any object using List & pass that data to MPAndroidChart libary.

MPAndroidChart has multiple graph choose according to your need.